# Node.js not picking up req.cookie

Tags: javascript, node.js

Experts,

I'm new to this, but I'm trying to implement some logic when a user is logged in. The login appears to work, as I get a successful login message and I can look at the cookies and the cookie exists:

[Cookie exists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZw0h.png)

However, when I try to access the cookie, Chrome tells me that it doesn't exist.

```
router.get('/', authController.isLoggedIn, viewsController.getOverview);
```

Here is my authController.isLoggedIn:

```
      exports.isLoggedIn = async (req, res, next) => {
          if (!req.cookies) {
            console.log('no cookies');
            return next();
          }
etc...
```

When that runs, I get the "no cookies" message in my console, so we're already dead in the water before any logic is applied.

Can anyone help me diagnose what I'm missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the structure of the `req` object? Are you using a framework that provides the structure of `req` and `res`? It could be that the structure of `req` is not what you're expecting, depending on how it's called.

Comment: Looks like you're using Express, have you added the `cookie-parser` middleware properly? `var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'); app.use(cookieParser());`

Comment: @Mackers I console.logged it - the cookie appears in req.headers, so I was able to read it and apply the logic. I was doing a node.js bootcamp on Udemy, though, and we used req.cookie there, and it worked fine. I couldn't, for the life of me, figure out the difference - I think we were using express in both cases.

Comment: @esqew I did not - I added it and that also fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookies aren't parsed by Express by default. You have to install the `cookie-parser` middleware to get them to populate into `req.cookies`. Run `npm install --save cookie-parser`, then configure similar to:

```
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
app.use(cookieParser());
```

This is clearly documented as part of [Express' official documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cookie-parser.html).

Comment: what if a person has already done this and cookies still aren't being picked up on the backend? In my case, the cookies have been working great for most requests, but for one that I am currently implementing, req.cookies is empty for some reason.

Comment: @the_mackster There are too many variables to answer based on the information you can squeeze into a comment and would likely warrant its own separate question (that is, if it’s not a duplicate of another already on the site).